# Make posts 410 dynamically

Tags: redirect

I have a site where posts get created and expired often. I want to add 410 status code to all posts that expire so that Search Engines remove them.

I want to know if wordpress provides a provision to do this? or is this possible at all? Any suggestions how to achieve this would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What do you call expired posts?

Comment: expired posts are nothing but posts status changed to draft. I don't want google to crawl them any longer hence I want to make them as 410.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did some testing and seems there is a bug here.

Newly created draft posts are not accessible on front-end. Search bot (or anyone else not logged in and using special preview URL) gets 404 error on them.

But if you publish and change back to draft then post remains available by direct link (does get removed from index).

For this reason I would stay away from using draft for this purpose. I would try to use custom field to mark post as expired and filter `the_content` to show informational message and set headers with [`status_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/status_header) function.

Comment: Thanks for the function Rarst. My posts are already indexed, so I have to remove them. There is one more issue here, I am able to set the header to 410, however, I want wordpress to show 410.php page when requests is made for these url's. I have created 410 page, but still that page is not being displayed. How do I make that 410 page appear for these url's?

Comment: You mean 410 page as error page in your hosting settings or in WP? Such hosting functionality mostly gets overridden with WP. Sorry, I have no idea how to handle this perfectly... Especially because of seemingly bugged draft mechanics.